# Receiving push notifications twice

Tags: c#, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

We have been using Firebase to send push notifications for a couple of months in our app, and I have used it in other of my apps . Everything had gone well, however a week ago we started receiving duplicate notifications (not always). The strange thing is that we did not change any code, it just started to happen in both Android and iOS. It only happens sometimes not always, and only in some users/devices.

I want to know if someone else is going through this with Firebase. I think it is a  Firebase bug but I would like to see if someone can confirm something about it.

The ios app is made in swift, and the android app in Java.

BTW. We are sending it based on this with FCM in our back-end. And we have no duplicated topics. I have checked and devices are only subscribed once.

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA
{
  "to": "/topics/foo-bar",
  "data": {
    "message": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
   }
}
```

Here my c# code in our back-end to send notifications

```
public void sendPushNotification(string _title, string _message, string _topic, object customData = null)
    {
        var requestUri = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

        WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", FCM_SERVER_API_KEY));
        webRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", FCM_SENDER_ID));
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

        var data = new
        {
            to = "/topics/" + _topic, // this is for topic 
            notification = new
            {
                title = _title,
                body = _message,
                sound = "default"
            },
            data = customData, //custom data (got it from firebase documentation)
            content_available = true 
        };

        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var json = serializer.Serialize(data);
        Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
        webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        using (Stream dataStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

            using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream dataStreamResponse = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
                    {
                        String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I too was having similar problem, I thought its firebase but its not. Check your logic for sending notifications. RegIds is being returned twice. If you are using sql query to get RegIds, put DISTINCT in the query.

Comment: We are sending notifications via topics (I have updated the question). Thank you very much but i thing it's not our case.

Comment: Are you positive that it's a duplicate message and not just a delayed message being received with a new one? There was a [latency issue](http://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Cloud%20Messaging/18016) that might've caused it. If it is an actual duplicate, then it might be a bug -- I suggest reaching out to Firebase support directly.

Comment: I’m pretty sure it’s a duplicated message and not a delayed one. I have sent a bug report to Firebase support, thank you for the advice. I just want to know if someone is facing the same issue.